# Android BroadcastReceiver or simple callback method?

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, broadcastreceiver

In my projects I am using `BroadcastReceiver`s as a callback from a long running thread (eg. notify the activity that a download was finished and send some response data from a Worker `Thread` so that the activity can display the appropriate message to the user..). 
To use `BroadcastReceiver`s I have to be careful to register and unregister the broadcast receiver each time I am using it and also have to care of what messages to send esspecialy when I am using this method for more different actions(like downloading, making WebService calls etc..). And also to send custom Objects through Broadcast's intent I need also to make the objects `Parcelable`.

Unlike this approach, I have seen also the callback methods approach which appears to be simpler than the method I use. Callback methods are simple Interface methods implementation that can be used to achieve the same effect like the BroadcastRecaiver's in app messaging.
This approach doesn't need Parcelable implementation to return complex objects and it doesn't use keys like `BroadcastReceiver`.. I think the bad part is that I need to check the callback object for null value before I want to call a callback method.. and also to make sure I am running the code from the implementation on the UI thread so I can update the UI without errors.

Ok, I hope you understood what I meant to say :).

Now the question is do you think that the callback method is better (lighter, cleaner, faster..) than the `BroadcastReceiver` approach when are used just inside of a single application? (Note that I am not using Android `Service` for background work.. just `AsyncTask` and `Thread`s)

Thank you!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is a very interesting question and I ran into the same problem. In my opinion both mechanisms can be used altogether and the right approach to use depends on your use case. Here are some points to be taken into account before deciding.

Using the callback-mechanism has some benefits, but there are also limitations:

PRO

- It is simple and straight forward to implement.
- You get type-safety between the components that interact with each other.
- You can return arbitrary objects.
- It simplifies testing as you only have to inject a mock-callback (e.g. generated through mockito or something similar) in unit tests.

CONTRA

- You have to switch to the main thread in order to do UI manipulations.
- You can only have a 1-to-1 relationship. A 1-to-n relationship (observer pattern) is not realizable without further work. In this case I would prefer Android's `Observer` / `Observable` mechanism.
- As you already said, you always have to check for `null` before invoking callback functions if the callback may be optional.
- If your component should offer a kind of service API with different service functions and you do not want to have a callback interface with only a few generic callback functions, you have to decide whether you provide a special callback interface for each service function or whether you provide a single callback interface with a lot of callback functions. In the later case all callback clients used for service calls to your API have to implement the complete callback interface although the majority of the method bodies will be empty. You can work around this by implementing a stub with empty bodies and make your callback client inherit from that stub, but this is not possible if already inheriting from another base class. Maybe you can use some kind of dynamic proxy callback (see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), but then it gets really complex and I would think of using another mechanism.
- The client for the callback calls has to be propagated through various methods/components if it is not directly accessible by the caller of the service.

Some points regarding the `BroadcastReceiver`-approach:

PRO

- You achieve a loose coupling between your components.
- You can have a 1-to-n relationship (including 1-to-0).
- The `onReceive()` method is always executed on the main thread.
- You can notify components in your entire application, so the communicating components do not have to "see" eachother.

CONTRA

- This is a very generic approach, so marshalling and unmarshalling of data transported by the `Intent` is an additional error source.
- You have to make your `Intent`'s actions unique (e.g. by prepending the package name) if you want to eliminate correlations with other apps, as their original purpose is to do broadcasts between applications.
- You have to manage the `BroadcastReceiver`-registration and unregistration. If you want to do this in a more comfortable way, you can implement a custom annotation to annotate your Activity with the actions that should be registered and implement a base `Activity`class that does registration and unregistration with `IntentFilter`s in its `onResume()` resp. `onPause()`methods.
- As you already said, the data that is sent with the `Intent` has to implement the `Parcelable` interface, but furthermore there is a strict size limitation and it will cause performance issues if you transport a large amount of data with your `Intent`. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5878 for a discussion on that. So if you want to send images for example you have to store them temporary in a repository and send a corresponding ID or URL to access the image from the receiver of your `Intent` that deletes it from the repository after usage. This leads to further problems if there are several receivers (when should the image be removed from the repository and who should do that?).
- If you overuse this kind of notification mechanism the control flow of your application may get hidden and when debugging you end up drawing graphs with sequences of `Intent`s to understand what has triggered a specific error or why this notification chain is broken at some point.

In my opinion, even a mobile app should have an architecture base on at least 2 layers: the UI-layer and the core layer (with business logic, etc.). In general, long running tasks are executed in an own thread (maybe via `AsyncTask` or `HandlerThread` if using `MessageQueue`s) inside the core layer and the UI should be updated once this task has been finished. In general with callbacks you achieve a tight coupling between your components, so I would prefer using this approach only within a layer and not for communication across layer boundaries. For message broadcasting between UI- and core-layer I would use the `BroadcastReceiver`-approach that lets you decouple your UI layer from the logic layer.

Comment: I have awarded this as an answer and give it the bounty because is the most complete answer.. Thank you all for your thoughts!

Comment: Excellent answer. I am a fan of the callback/interface pattern but I often inherit projects with extensive usage of the Broadcast intent pattern and I often wonder if I am going the wrong way about it. It is nice to hear that really it is a matter of design preference rather than best practice. I like the type-safety and code clarity offered by interfaces and I shall probably stick to them for now

Comment: very interesting and detailed opinion +1

Comment: You can use the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to keep your broadcasts local to your app. This helps prevent some issues with app crossover, and peace of mind on where your data is going.

Comment: There aren't two options here. There are many. I would never entirely rule out an EventBus, RxJava Subject, or application-level objects. Each has its advantages and disadvantages in different situations.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see what you gain by using `BroadcastReceiver` in your case. Callbacks or, better probably, `Handlers` would be the way to do it. `BroadcastReceiver` is good when you do not know who the subscribers are.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add another option to the other great answers you've received already...

You don't have to create a broadcast receiver to receive Intents. In your android manifest file you can register any activity to receive intents:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter >
              <action android:name="intent.you.want.to.receive" /> 
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>     
....
</activity>
```

Then override the `onNewIntent(Intent)` method in your activity to receive it.

To send the Intent, use the `Context.startActivity(Intent)` method. Most likely you'll want to add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag to your Intent so it doesn't create a new instance of your activity if one is already running.

EDIT: I just noticed you are running within a single application. Therefore, a simple callback is probably best. The solution above does work in a single app, but is more appropriate for different applications. I'll leave this here just in case it helps someone. Good luck!

Comment: Excelent tip! I'd like to add, though, that the same `<intent-filter>` approach applies to services as well, if you'd like to isolate non-UI specific implementations, in which case you'd call `Context.startService(Intent)` instead. If your target service extends [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) you'll have an "asynchronous message queue" for free as the `IntentService` will only execute on one `Intent` at the time and the `onHandleIntent` method will be executed on a worker thread.

Answer (score 2):

Broadcastreceivers should be used If you need to send broadcasts across applications while Callbacks (or Handlers as suggested by Alex) are better to use in your situation.

If you want to use other than these two, consider using [Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html) (Interface included in android) and delegate.

For delegate please consider [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154932/how-to-implement-event-and-delegate-concept-in-android).

Answer (score 1):

not sure what the goal is , but if you wish to keep the same idea of using intent and broadcastReceiver , and want better performance and security than normal broadcastReceivers , you can try out this demo , available in the android support library :

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/content/LocalServiceBroadcaster.html

if not , you can always use asyncTask , service , handlers , etc...