# Android - Connect to event in service

Tags: android, service

I have a background service (in library) that start with `START_STICKY` command. This service propose is to run in the background, that checks state of some values of the phone. After some calculation of the values its need to emit event. I need to connect activity to the service and show notification (the code of both is not in the library)  when the service emit its event.

I have some confuse with the implements of the event. I saw in the in tutorials some ways but I don't know what is the best solution for this situation. broadcasts? listeners? binder?
Can someone explain what is the advantage and disadvantage of each way, and what recommended to use in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalBroadcastManager if they run in the same process. It's the easiest solution and it provides several advantages like low coupling compared with binder.

Comment: It is better then listener?

Comment: Please ser this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575239/android-broadcastreceiver-or-simple-callback-method